# python HTTP error 302

Tags: python, html, urllib

i keep getting an html 302 error however i am quite certain the error is coming
from some code in here i just don't know where exactly and how to fix it.

```
headers ={'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8','Connection': 'keep-alive'}

req_obj = urllib.request.Request(url, method=method,headers=headers)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor())
response = opener.open(req_obj)
json_resp = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

and the error I get it is

```
HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found

(False, <HTTPError 302: 'The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.\nThe last 30x error message was:\nFound'>)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of `url`?

Comment: url = 'https://practicelogin.questrade.com/'

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of the server you're trying to access. The `Location` parameter of the header is the same as the URL you're trying to access, which would result in an infinite loop.

For instance, if I were to go to `http://example.com/foo`, and it told me that the resource had been moved to `http://example.com/foo`, I would go to `http://example.com/foo` as requested. However, this would tell me that `http://example.com/foo` had been moved to `http://example.com/foo`. So on and so forth.